# Within returns results despite there is no points inside the selected polygon

Tags: java, hibernate-spatial

I have a method that uses within function, in order to check if a point is within a polygon:

```
public List<PointsEntity> findPointsIntoAnExistingPolygon(PolygonEntity polygon) {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();       sb.append("select p from PointsEntity p, PolygonEntity poly "       + "where within(p.coordinates, poly.coordinates) = true");
                Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString());
                        List<PointsEntity> pointFound = new ArrayList<PointsEntity>();
                try {           pointFound =  (List<PointsEntity>) q.getResultList();           }catch(NoResultException nre){          }
                return pointFound;  }
```

But it returns all the points in the DB that there are into a polygon.

For example, if I pass as a parameter a polygon A that doesn´t contain a point, the method returns the point that is contained by polygon B instead of return nothing.

Comment: And where in that query do you constrain polygons to restrict them to A?

Comment: If I understand well your answer, the parameter polygon it´s unique, as it has an unique ID. Before to use that method, I use another method that retrieves one polygon from the DB, and this polygon with its id and coordinates is passed in the method shown